# Got "java.io.IOException: Premature EOF" error randomly when retrieve large data from Salesforce

Tags: bulk-api

When we use salesforce bulk query to retrieve data from salesforce module.
There are more than 10 million records in the target module.
we got this kind of error randomly:

```
[FATAL]: local_project711.identify_duplicate_data_job_3_0_1.identify_duplicate_data_job_3 - tSalesforceInput_1 Premature EOF
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.fastRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(Unknown Source)
at com.csvreader.CsvReader.checkDataLength(Unknown Source)
at com.csvreader.CsvReader.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at org.talend.components.salesforce.runtime.BulkResultSet.next(BulkResultSet.java:21)
at org.talend.components.salesforce.runtime.SalesforceBulkQueryInputReader.advance(SalesforceBulkQueryInputReader.java:69)
at org.talend.codegen.flowvariables.runtime.FlowVariablesReader.advance(FlowVariablesReader.java:78)
at local_project711.identify_duplicate_data_job_3_0_1.identify_duplicate_data_job_3.tSalesforceInput_1Process(identify_duplicate_data_job_3.java:38470)
at local_project711.identify_duplicate_data_job_3_0_1.identify_duplicate_data_job_3.runJobInTOS(identify_duplicate_data_job_3.java:56075)
at local_project711.identify_duplicate_data_job_3_0_1.identify_duplicate_data_job_3.main(identify_duplicate_data_job_3.java:55907)
```

Our configuration:
Java 8
URL: "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0"
Lib: 
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/force/api/force-partner-api/44.0.0/force-partner-api-44.0.0.jar
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/force/api/force-wsc/44.0.0/force-wsc-44.0.0.jar
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/javacsv/javacsv/2.0/javacsv-2.0.jar

Steps we do in our application:
https://github.com/Talend/components/blob/master/components/components-salesforce/components-salesforce-runtime/src/main/java/org/talend/components/salesforce/runtime/SalesforceSourceOrSink.java#L120
https://github.com/Talend/components/blob/master/components/components-salesforce/components-salesforce-runtime/src/main/java/org/talend/components/salesforce/runtime/SalesforceBulkQueryInputReader.java
https://github.com/Talend/components/blob/master/components/components-salesforce/components-salesforce-runtime/src/main/java/org/talend/components/salesforce/runtime/SalesforceBulkRuntime.java

1. create BulkConnection instance
2. create a bulk job and retrieve batchinfolist and resultIDs when batch complete
3. iterator every resultset and got result content

Then the error would throw when iterate record from resultset **RANDOMLY**.
https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-42582
This was reported in our JIRA.

Any suggestion about this error.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using [PK Chunking](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_curl_walkthrough_pk_chunking.htm)? What batch size, if so?

Comment: we tried PK chunking, and batch size is 100000. doesn't work in our test cause.(we loop query 2.6 million records as we don't have 10 million records in our salesforce server) waiting feedback from our customer who have the large data